# Full body movement control over games + Speed reduction in visual c#

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to recreate FAAST in C# using full body movement sequences instead of threshold triggers.
Before recreating the wheel has anyone already done this or something similar I can reuse?

Also, why is the Windows Kinect SDK using Visual C# slower in it's presentation of the skeleton than processing using simpleopenni? On the same machine I have 30fps with processing and about 8fps with the kinect sdk and vc#.

Comment: You should ask only one question at a time. If you have more questions, post them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not much of a kinect expert but maybe this could be a good starting point:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213034/Kinect-Getting-Started-Become-The-Incredible-Hulk